# In App Purchase for iPhone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing a iPhone app. For that i have successfully add the In App Purchase functionality. It is working perfectly for a single item purchase. My problem is that How can i do this for multiple item purchase with single purchase request to App Store?
Can anybody help me for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **quantity** property in *SKPayment*... Read how many items you want from user then pass this value to **payment.quantity**(By default it is 1).

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:inProductID];
payment.quantity = mNoOfItemsYouWant;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:mTransactionObserver];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Comment: Hi Chandan, thanks for reply. I have tried your solution but it gives error for
payment.quantity = 4 as "Object can not be set - either readonly property or no setter found.
Can you please explain why is it showing above error?

Comment: Hi Chandan,
I found the solution why that error was coming.
I just replace SKPayment with SKMutablePayment. and it works.

Comment: @Shakti, How did you implement multiple purchasing in one click? Can you post piece of code? quantity only sets up count of products, but how can I set purchasable products?  Thanks

Comment: HI Shamsiddin Saidov
Sorry for late reply.
You have to pass an Array of product IDs to SKMutablePayment request.
And For quantity pass the array count to it.

Answer (score 0):

Each purchase needs authorization from the user, so I don't think you can do what you want to.

However, you can make a single in-app purchase which is priced and behaves like multiple items clubbed together. For instance:

- Item 1 - $.99
- Item 2 - $.99
- Item 3 - $.99
- Bundle (includes 1, 2, 3) - $1.99